# POSIX function to search PATH for an executable?

Tags: c, unix, path, posix

Is there a POSIX function that searches `PATH` for an executable according to the [POSIX spec's description of the `PATH` environment variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) and returns the absolute path to the executable?

If not, is there a simple, safe, standard, and reliable way to search `PATH`?

**Edit:**
[glibc's `execvpe()` function](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/execvpe.c) does its own `PATH` search, so I'm guessing there isn't a specific `PATH` search function defined by the standard.

**Edit 2:**  I don't want to copy someone else's code or implement the `PATH` search myself for a few reasons:

- [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
- More code I have to test and maintain
- Possible licensing issues
- POSIX says, "If `PATH` is unset or is set to null, the path search is implementation-defined."  I would like the behavior in these cases to be consistent with whatever the system does, but I can't do this if there's not a standard function I can call.

Comment: `execvp` and `execlp` are POSIX standard functions. Are you looking for a function that *just* searches `$PATH`?

Comment: @larsmans:  yes, and returns a string containing the full path to the executable (if found)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a POSIX function that searches PATH for an executable according to the POSIX spec's description of the PATH environment variable and returns the absolute path to the executable?

No.

> If not, is there a simple, safe, standard, and reliable way to search PATH?

Yes and no. Yes, there is a standard for the format of `PATH`, from which the correctness/reliability of implementations follow.

No, there is no standard function that does this. Copying code is your best bet.

> If `PATH` is unset or is set to null, the path search is implementation-defined.

That means you can't always *portably* replicate what `execvp` does, but searching `/bin:/usr/bin` is a pretty safe bet. Alternatively, just raise an error in this case.

(I admit that it would have been nice if POSIX had had this function, but it just isn't there.)

Answer (score 4):

The command line tool `which` will do that. [here's the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which)

[and the source](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/which/which.c?root=which&view=markup)

Comment: I don't consider adapting hundreds of lines of someone else's code to be simple.

Comment: If there were a simple way to do it, it would've been done already. It's not part of the posix spec.

Comment: It's very simple. Iterating over the elements of `$PATH` is a couple lines of C. If anything, the reason it's not in POSIX is that it's *too simple*, i.e. trivial to do yourself so it didn't merit somebody inventing a new interface.

Comment: @R..:  It's not as easy as two lines of code; witness the size and complexity of the two aforementioned implementations.  Some of the issues that have to be dealt with:  `PATH` is null, `PATH` is empty, `PATH` starts with `:`, `PATH` ends with `:`, `PATH` contains `::`, reporting user-friendly errors, dealing with idiosyncratic filesystem behavior, etc.

Comment: Starting or ending with `:` is not special; it's a zero-length path component just like `::`, which must be interpreted as `.` (unfortunately). These are all covered by one case after the next path component is obtained. It would be ugly on two lines of code, but I could see writing the whole function cleanly in under 10 lines.

Comment: GNU implementations of Unix tools tend to be overly complicated. Check out the `findprog` function from [OpenBSD `which`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/which/which.c?rev=1.17); non-trivial, but a lot simpler than the GNU one.

Comment: @larsmans good point. The bsd implementation is much smaller.

Comment: Here's the BSD implementation: https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libc/gen/exec.c#L131 (This is in the OpenBSD libc but it's very similar in the other BSDs as their libc's are derived from the same code). It's definitely not something an average programmer could duplicate easily.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like:

```
FILE *f = popen("command -v somecommand", "r")
```

and then read its output?  This would result in behavior that matches the system's handling of empty/unset `PATH`, and it may be simpler than manually searching `PATH`.

There are some drawbacks to this approach:

- If `somecommand` comes from the user, it may have to be sanitized to prevent code injection attacks.  That would add to the complexity.
- Reliably reading the stream while handling all possible error cases is not trivial.  More complexity.
- If `somecommand` is a shell special built-in (e.g., `set`), it'll return bogus results.  This case should be detectable, but then what?  More complexity.