# How to find the full pathname of a binary within C?

Tags: c, linux, path

I am writing a simple app in C that is meant to act as a shell. It takes user input from stdin, stores it as a string, and then uses execl with that string to execute it in the terminal as a binary executable. However, execl does not take binaries in the form of "ls" or "who", but instead it expects their absolute pathname. What can I do, within my C code, to find the full pathname of a given binary executable without a specified path, so that I only have to enter executable binaries such as "ls" and "who" into standard input, and execl can still be given their full pathnames. I am doing this on a Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `execlp` or `execvp` instead of `execl` or `execvp`. The `p` versions of these calls search `PATH` to find the executable if it doesn't contain any slashes.

Comment: Assuming I wanted to keep execl(), is there anything I could do to find the full pathname, representing it as string, so that I could enter that string into the execl() function?

Comment: Use `getenv("PATH")` to get the path, split it up at the `:` characters, loop through each directory, appending the name to the directory and trying to exec it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058574/posix-function-to-search-path-for-an-executable

Comment: Why don't you want to use `execle`?

Comment: @Br0f1st if you're running on a linux distro that happens to have the `locate` application installed, you could run that and parse the output.

Comment: @BrandonYates `locate` doesn't use your search path, it just looks for any files anywhere on the system that have a particular name.

Comment: Correct - searching path is definitely preferable. Just giving another option because OP seems to not want to use path for some reason.